# Unable to recognize gestures on a subview in a GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, gmsmapview

I currently have a GMSMapView with a UIView subview, but I can't get the subview to recognize tap gestures. I've tried many solutions like setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` equal to true and overriding the `delegate` but none have worked so far.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
class MapViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var testView: UIView!
    var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 0, longitude: 0, zoom: 15.0)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height

        testView = UIView()
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        testView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0);
        testView.frame.size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        testView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.doSomething(_:)))
        gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        gesture.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(testView)
        testView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func doSomething(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("doSomething")
    } 

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if (touch.view == gestureRecognizer.view) {
            print("returned true")
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

The interesting thing is that when I do tap on `testView`, it does print out "returned true" from my `shouldReceiveTouch` function. So I'm not quite sure how the delegate function returns true, yet the selector function isn't firing. I also tried this swipe gestures with another UIView and that did not work either. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't one supposed to tap the map to zoom in?  You can't add a tap gesture to MKMapView.  That's probably true for the Google map view.

Comment: @ElTomato even if the tap gesture is for a view on the mapview, not the actual mapview itself?

Comment: As for MKMapView, no.  I don't know for GMSMapView since I don't have quick access to a sample project I have made a year ago.

Comment: @ElTomato Just curious, is this from experience or was this documented somewhere?

Comment: @ElTomato also if that is true that I can't add a tap gesture, then why is `shouldReceive` being called?

Comment: That's from my experience for macOS.  I don't remember doing it for iOS.  I don't know about shouldReceive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following code:

```
mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
```

From the [Google Maps iOS SDK Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#a18ee69e2a06e4934beb9103663d6a73f):

> Controls whether gestures by users are completely consumed by the
>   GMSMapView when gestures are enabled (default YES). This prevents
>   these gestures from being received by parent views.
>
> When the GMSMapView is contained by a UIScrollView (or other
>   scrollable area), this means that gestures on the map will not be
>   additional consumed as scroll gestures. However, disabling this (set
>   to NO) may be useful to support complex view hierarchies or
>   requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer worked! Would you mind adding the link to where you found this in your answer? I think it would definitely help me and others.

Comment: I didn't find it in docs. I'm currently working on a map-based application where I faced the same situation and with some hit and trails, I found this.

Comment: no problem, I was able to do some searching and found that it came from the google maps ios sdk reference. Added the link to your answer, thanks again!